# Путаница при проверке поддержки интерфейса

Tags: c++, directx, dxgi

Структура `dxgi_adapter`:

```
typedef struct dxgi_adapter
{
    IDXGIAdapter1                       *p_adapter;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1                  m_adapter_desc;
    std::vector<dxgi_adapter_output>    m_outputs;
    bool check_support(REFGUID ref_iid) const;
} dxgi_adapter_t;

bool dxgi_adapter::check_support(REFGUID ref_iid) const
{
    return SUCCEEDED(p_adapter->CheckInterfaceSupport(ref_iid, nullptr));
}
```

По непонятным мне причинам, при попытке вызова проверки интерфейса

```
if(!p_helper_->primary_adapter().check_support(__uuidof(ID3D12Device)))
{
    char buffer[255] = {0};
    sprintf_s(buffer, "Primary adapter %ls does not support Direct3D 12 interface",
            p_helper_->primary_adapter().m_adapter_desc.Description);

    PRINT_MSG(buffer);
    p_helper_.release();
    throw std::runtime_error(buffer);
}
```

Всегда получаю

> [ 000000874492F898 (renderer) ] Error: Primary adapter Radeon 550
>   Series does not support Direct3D 12 interface

При этом, я точно знаю что он поддерживает данный интерфейс.

Как правильно проверить поддержку `Direct 3D 12 Api` не прибегая к вызову `D3D12CreateDevice`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот метод можно использовать только для проверки поддержки интерфейсов Direct3D 10.x. Из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiadapter-checkinterfacesupport)

> **Remarks**
>
> Note  You can use `CheckInterfaceSupport` only to check whether a Direct3D 10.x interface is supported, and only on Windows Vista SP1 and later versions of the operating system. If you try to use `CheckInterfaceSupport` to check whether a Direct3D 11.x and later version interface is supported, `CheckInterfaceSupport` returns `DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED`. Therefore, do not use `CheckInterfaceSupport`. Instead, to verify whether the operating system supports a particular interface, try to create the interface. For example, if you call the `ID3D11Device::CreateBlendState` method and it fails, the operating system does not support the `ID3D11BlendState` interface.)

Comment: Т.е. как я понимаю все-таки придется пробовать создать `ID3D12Device`?

Comment: @LLENN Видимо да.